# Compare value in vector with all other vectors

Tags: r

**Let's assume following dataset:**

```
+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
| flightCarrier | saleTotal | daysBeforeDeparture |
+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
| KL            | 477.99    |                   0 |
| AF            | 457.99    |                   0 |
| SQ            | 556.31    |                   0 |
+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

**What I'd like to do is the following:**

1. Compare a value in a column to all other values in the same column.
2. Is saleTotal(1) is smaller than the value of saleTotal(2) and saleTotal(3)
3. If yes, by how much? saleTotal(3)/saleTotal(1)

***Workorder***:

- 477,99 < 457,99 (false)
- 477,99 < 556.31 (true) -> (556.31/477.99)-1=1.16 (16% increase)
- 457.99 < 477.99 (true) -> .....
- 457.99 < 556.31 (true) -> .....
- 556.31 < 477.99 (false)
- 556.31 < 457.99 (false)

**What I've tried so far:**

```
cal <- apply(df_matrix[1:2,2], 1, function(x) {
  A <- x
  x <- x[-1]
  ifelse(x>A, 1, ifelse(x<A, 0, NA))
})
cal
```

This didn't worked out and prints out "logical(0)" so I guess no results.
I tried lots of ways, with lapply, mapply but all seemed to go comparing static numbers instead of previous rows.

What I grasped from apply yet, is that every X there is the row its "iterating". Thats why I tried to compare X>A while A is the whole vector with all saleTotal values. Thus, iterating through each of one.

---

**Expected Output** 
*Business Output: "Price is cheaper than XY other prices"*

I guess this would be the best way to avoid large matrices and keep memory as low as possible)
Is there might be a way to "nrow()" the results directly rather than creating a matrices/list first?

```
+-----------+-------------+
| saleTotal | cheaperThan |
+-----------+-------------+
| 477.99    |           1 |
| 457.99    |           2 |
| 556.31    |           0 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Any idea how to do this? What about performance, I have 100000+ rows?

EDIT: expected output (one way)

Comment: Take a look at `outer(df$saleTotal, df$saleTotal, "/")` values greater 1 indicate increase, values less than 1 indicate decrease and the diagonal of the matrix is all 1s since it compares each value to itself.

Comment: What exactly is the wanted output? What happens with the `<` comparisons that give `FALSE`? Your 'workorder' indicates a simple loop like `lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) x[-i][x[[i]] < x[-i]] / x[[i]])`

Comment: The output wanted based on the example could be simply 1 column with 3 rows with the value of the change in it. I'll give you're solution a try, thanks!

Comment: @s1x show the expected output for your example input...

Comment: @s1x and in your code, at first iteration x is the `saleTotal` value of first row, on second iteration, the value of this column for second row. (and this will stop there as you filter your data on two rows), hence, x[-1] does no exist.

Comment: It seems that you'll need `findInterval`; `length(x) - findInterval(x, sort(x))` should be efficient enough.

Comment: @alexis_laz you should post this as an answer, (and if someone is curious enough to benchmark the solutions that would be great I think (I assume `findInterval` will be quicker) ;p)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**See note at end about efficiency**

With your expected output you may iterate on each value and count (sum the `TRUE` values) how many time this value is cheaper than all the others values and return a list to 'pair' the value with the count:

```
sapply(data[,2],function(x) {
  list(x, sum(x < data[,2]))
})
```

which gives in long format:

```
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
[1,] 477.99 457.99 556.31
[2,] 1      2      0
```

In case you just wish to add a column to your existing dataset this should do:

```
data$cheaperThan <- sapply(data[,2],function(x) sum(x < data[,2]))
```

Data used:

```
> system.time(sapply(large,function(x) sum(x < large)))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       1.08        0.22        1.30 
> system.time(length(large) - findInterval(large,sort(large)))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       0.01        0.00        0.01
```

@alexis_laz solution if really really really more efficient:

```
> set.seed(123)
> test <- runif(50000)*100
> identical(sapply(test,function(x) sum(x < test)), (length(test) - findInterval(test,sort(test))))
[1] TRUE
> system.time(sapply(test,function(x) sum(x < test)))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      13.64        1.24       14.96 
> system.time(length(test) - findInterval(test,sort(test)))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       0.01        0.00        0.02
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect this work well with a large dataset (@alexis_laz for efficient solution).  @docendo discimus solutions works too - but uses a lot of memory due to the output format. Hence, depending on the output, you could use both.

Comment: I guess `sum(x < x)` and `findinterval(x, sort(x))` are conceptually the same but the cost of `sort`ing once should always outweigh the `length(x) * length(x)` looping, at least for large vectors. I think `findInterval` is one of the few 'panacea-functions' in R... :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `?outer` like this:

```
outer(df$saleTotal, df$saleTotal, "/")
#          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 1.0000000 1.043669 0.8592152
#[2,] 0.9581581 1.000000 0.8232640
#[3,] 1.1638528 1.214677 1.0000000
```

Values greater 1 indicate increase, values less than 1 indicate decrease and the diagonal of the matrix is all 1s since it compares each value to itself.

Of course you could modify this to only show values greater than 1, for example by using:

```
res <- outer(df$saleTotal, df$saleTotal, "/")
res * as.integer(res > 1)
#         [,1]     [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 0.000000 1.043669    0
#[2,] 0.000000 0.000000    0
#[3,] 1.163853 1.214677    0
```

Or, if you just want a logical matrix:

```
res > 1
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Works like a charm with my small sample. With 50,000 rows: "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 24.2 Gb"; So outer seems to not work with large datasets here cause Its building up a huge matrix.

Comment: @s1x, I see what you mean. You should be more specific about your desired output as asked by alexis_laz. In case you want a result for each comparison, it's gonna be difficult with other approaches too, I think (how much ram do you have?)

Comment: @s1x If each value has to be compared to all other, the resulting vector will obviously be at least `factorial(length(data[,'saleTotal']))` anyway...